# How to configure test instance in svcutil.exe for soap based apis?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, soap, soapui, svcutil.exe

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the `svcutil.exe` tool from the command line with the following syntax:

```
svcutil.exe http://testdomain.svc?wsdl
```

This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service

I didnt understood how to configure the Instance.

Comment: Could you add link to source of "...how to configure the Instance."? to make more clear what you mean.